# Rails app to deploy another Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, nginx, unicorn

I have had a quick look on google to no avail.

I am looking for a way to write a rails app that can deploy another rails app using nginx unicorn and what ever else is necessary to get the job done.

Ideal the user would be presented with a screen where they would enter username password, email and sitename.

Then the app would create the site and give it the url sitename.appname.com

Thanks

Ash

Answer (score 0):

They are called engineyard, and heroku.

Rails probably wouldn't do much but give you the control panel, all the magic would be behind the scenes.  If you are just subdomaining an existing app, rails can do that too and you wouldn't need a new nginx/unicorn on each subdomain either.

The typical answer of "it depends on your app and there is not enough information to go on" applies as well.

Comment: Thanks for this :) I am actually looking for pointers on how to do this as  would like to host the apps myself it would be quite similar to how shopify works [link](http://www.shopify.com) they just get a sitename email and password and your off :)

Comment: you'll want to structure your questions around things like `how do i use subdomains in rails to create a multi tennant experience for my users`  You're undertaking a big step mate.